# For a D range, should front() be a @property?

Tags: properties, iterator, range, d

When I define my D range, should `front()` be a @property? (or just a 
"regular" member function?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is supposed to be (the formal definition is under the `isInputRange` template in the docs, see: http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.range.primitives.isInputRange.html ).

In practice, it may work anyway, but since the docs say it and `typeof(range.front)` is a common check in range constraints and that is the one thing `@property` will actually change in the dmd implementation right now, it is best to use it to be compliant.

Now, `@property` currently does not prohibit calling it like `range.front()`, with parenthesis, you should NOT do that, since at some point in the future, @property might change to block that behavior.

So yeah, use `@property` on range.front and always use it as a property for maximum forward compatibility.